# What are the best practices for using a webView in android? can we use webview in each row in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, performance

i'm working on a recyclerview where i'm using a webView in each viewHolder. But the webview tends to lag pretty much. Actually i'm using highcharts ( a js chart library ) to render charts, and it automatically animates the chart. because of this lag the animation stutters. Is it a best practice to use webview in recyclerview and viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple webviews, try to use a single webview which acts as a recycler view for your app(i.e. as a list).
It will also speed up your app, as it will have to render only once instead of rendering the same charts library over and over again for each viewholder